# Automounter CentOS Linux 5.5

Tags: linux, nfs

How can I create a auto.home file to mount certain /home directories via local disk and others via NFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the **autofs** package which can do this for you.

In /etc/auto.master, you'd put:

```
/home    /etc/auto.home
```

And in /etc/auto.home:

```
user1    my.other.machine:/path/to/user1
```

Comment: be carefull with nfs over wifi.

Comment: I use NFS over wifi all the time.  Works great (just a bit slower).  Granted, it'll be a **whole** lot worse for home directories.

Comment: What syntax do I use in auto.home to mount some home directories via local disk, and some via NFS?

Comment: for a local disk, use "user1 -fstype=auto :/dev/sdb44" for example